# Django Rest Framework Json data monkey patching

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework, monkeypatching

I'm Facing a problem with float number like **3.333333333** and I want to make it **3.33**. I don't want to change all `Serializer` class from where this type of value is coming. There are thousand serializers and they have multiple fields which have values like **3.333333333**.

Could you please help me to find monkey patching type solution so that I'll write one class or function to convert only float values.

Comment: what's wrong with returning 3.333333? any consumer of your api can display it as 3.33. Let the client handle the formatting.

Comment: In Android, they need to specify the data type like float, int or long.
suppose initially data was **4.56** but now coming **3.3333333**.
so it is very difficult to change all float data type to long now. thats why i need solution at **back-end** not client end.

Comment: I suppose vinay is right, I have also faced the same issue. converting them from client side (especially android is not a good idea)  @vinaykumar, people will be happy to answer your question, if you also write down your attempts (what have you tried) with question. I guess you need to monkeypatch json.dumps which is getting called from JSONEncode class.

Comment: Are the serializer fields all of the same type? For instance `FloatField`?

Comment: @ilse2005 all field are not `FloatField`.
I am using DRF and mongoengine.

`class MyModel(me.Document):
           accuracy = me.DictField(default={})`
I am also using field like this.

Comment: Are you using ListView or generating json manually? What needs to be monkey patched?

Comment: @serg I am using ListView.

Comment: You are not using float fields you said, can you give an example then how would you manually convert one of your fields to the format you want.

Answer (score 1):

I did some code its working.
I made changes in following files

**settings.py**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
 'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (

    'utils.renderers.PalJSONRenderer',

    'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
 )}
```

**utils/renderers.py**

```
        from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
        from rest_framework.utils.encoders import JSONEncoder

        from json.encoder import encode_basestring_ascii, encode_basestring, INFINITY, _make_iterencode


        class CustomJSONEncoder(JSONEncoder):

            def iterencode(self, o, _one_shot=False):
                """Encode the given object and yield each string
                representation as available.

                For example::

                    for chunk in JSONEncoder().iterencode(bigobject):
                        mysocket.write(chunk)

                """
                # Hack to enforce
                c_make_encoder = None
                if self.check_circular:
                    markers = {}
                else:
                    markers = None
                if self.ensure_ascii:
                    _encoder = encode_basestring_ascii
                else:
                    _encoder = encode_basestring

                def floatstr(o, allow_nan=self.allow_nan, _repr=lambda o: format(o, '.2f'), _inf=INFINITY, _neginf=-INFINITY):
                    # Check for specials.  Note that this type of test is processor
                    # and/or platform-specific, so do tests which don't depend on the
                    # internals.

                    if o != o:
                        text = 'NaN'
                    elif o == _inf:
                        text = 'Infinity'
                    elif o == _neginf:
                        text = '-Infinity'
                    else:
                        return _repr(o)

                    if not allow_nan:
                        raise ValueError(
                            "Out of range float values are not JSON compliant: " +
                            repr(o))

                    return text

                if (_one_shot and c_make_encoder is not None and self.indent is None):
                    _iterencode = c_make_encoder(
                        markers, self.default, _encoder, self.indent,
                        self.key_separator, self.item_separator, self.sort_keys,
                        self.skipkeys, self.allow_nan)
                else:
                    _iterencode = _make_iterencode(
                        markers, self.default, _encoder, self.indent, floatstr,
                        self.key_separator, self.item_separator, self.sort_keys,
                        self.skipkeys, _one_shot)
                return _iterencode(o, 0)


        class PalJSONRenderer(JSONRenderer):
            encoder_class = CustomJSONEncoder
```